# send queued email when connected to internet

Tags: windows-phone-7, email

I am developing app in wp7 in which i have to send email.
there is one functionality is whenever the internet is not available it will put mail in queue and as phone connected to internet it will automatically send all the queued email.
so any one has idea how to implement this functionality in wp7?

Comment: How do you send the emails when you're online ?

Comment: Yes..When Ever My device get internet connection it will send all queued Email..

Answer (score 1):

You can have an background agent (executed once every 30 minutes) that will check if the connection is available nd if it is, sends the email.

Comment: I knew that but hoe to perform that in wp7-8?